# build method not working for multiple fields on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models.

Question.rb

```
Class Question
  belongs_to :quiz
  has_many :possible_answers
end
```

PossibleAnswer.rb

```
Class possible_answer
  belongs_to :question
end
```

I am trying to add multiple possible answers to a question by doing these changes to questions controller and form.

questions_controller.rb

```
def new
    @question = @quiz.questions.build
    5.times { @question.possible_answers.build }
end
```

_form.html.erb

```
<p>
  <label>Specify some choices:</label>
</p>
<%= f.fields_for :possible_answers do |c| %>
  <p>
    <%= c.text_field :title, placeholder: "Type your choice", class: "form-control" %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

By what I read it should give 5 fields to enter possible answers, but instead still giving single field. Can anybody please help me out here ?

Comment: Can you please add the code where you're using the `form_for`?

Comment: if you are you nested field then i suggest use https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon

Comment: add accepts_nested_attributes_for :possible_answers in question model  and try

Comment: follow this episodes step http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

Answer (score 0):

I think you must do it this way:

```
def new
   @question = @quiz.questions.build
   5.times { @question.possible_answers << Possible_answer.build }
end
```